# paragraph indentation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, editor

I've noticed a couple of questions that where completely formatted as "one line of code". They look like this:

```
   Hello, I have a question. Now I'm going to paste a lipsum: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

The actual text looks like a 'normal' paragraph like you would find in a book: The first line is indended, and there are no newlines.

Now it could be a "style", to indent your paragraph with some spaces used by users who do not know the formatting-rules for MarkDown and 'just like' that layout. But could it be an editor feature? Some editors maybe like to add an indentation like that? And If so (I am aware there are multiple ifs in this line of thought), could we pick that editor-feature up somehow, and maybe 'fix' it?

In summary:
Could there be a (technical?) reason this happens multiple times, and if so, why does it happen? If it is something the user does there is no 'answer', but if it is something the browser does, there might be a way to let it not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think is user should look at at preview before submitting an answer or question. But yes the suggestion is also good that editor should provide functionality like paragraph indentation.

Comment: I agree with that a user should look at the preview, but i didn't mean we should *add* that functionality, I was hoping that we could do something to remove the unintended indentation ;)

Comment: @Nanne: may be I interpreted your question wrong. ;-)

Comment: @Nanne, I don't understand what you're proposing either. For a start: try to summarize it in the question's title please?

Comment: I'll try to summarize :)

Answer (score 7):

Unless they are posting from mobile devices, where a preview is not available, I do not see any reason why they should not be able to see the effects of their 'text formatting' - it is, really, *very* obvious, and I won't put it down to anything other than laziness on the part of the OP.

And no, I do not think having an option to do this is useful. Indented text is hardly seen anywhere on the internet today, even if the ability to do so is provided very conveniently by the `text-indent` CSS property. Having the option to do every conceivable formatting possibility would the fastest way to get a WYSIWYG-eque editor:

[image: TinyMCE's 'full' option, with four row of buttons and every conceivable option]

Comment: Where's the kitchen sink icon?

Comment: @andrew only WordPress has that ;)   http://www.lgr.ca/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/wp-show-hide-kitchen-sink.gif