# Provide a warning for incomplete indentation when they miss it by that much

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, indentation

Would you believe that someone indented their code with three spaces, and got an error message letting them know that it won't work?

Find that hard to believe? Ok, would you believe they got a tool-tip warning?

It not appearing right in the preview box?

Comment: Instead, maybe we should add "3 spaces" to the [heuristics for detecting a bad answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer)? (Too bad this is not used for questions though?)

Comment: As an aside: [apparently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83813/paragraph-indentation/83820#83820) there is no preview on mobile devices. Still then, I fail to understand why a few people are not somehow alarmed seeing the result after posting...

Comment: @Arjan - They probably either don't care or don't know that they can indent another space to make it look like code.  Some people indent their code with the intention that it will merely be indented and then accidentally discover that is how the formatting works.

Comment: @jmort253: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5428751/revisions was an example of someone trying to indent their code, but had one space too few.

Comment: Can somebody run a query to find questions with lines that start with just 3 spaces to see how prevelant it is?

Answer (score 1):

I ran a query on SEDE, but I'm not going to share it because it takes ~50 seconds to run and I don't want that kind of load being put on SEDE by everyone who visits this question.

There were 132 occurances of lines indented with three spaces, and the vast majority of them were blank lines that just happened to have three spaces on them for some reason.

That's not enough to justify the additional overhead and development time of doing this IMO.

Comment: Did you look only at current posts, or original revisions, too? I would imagine that most of the 3-space lines would have been corrected by now, mostly by editors.

Comment: @Gabe - current posts only

Comment: I thought query results were saved? (At least when the query was saved?)

Comment: @arjan - well it took 50+ seconds every time, so I dunno?

Comment: "current posts only" indeed doesn't tell us anything as @Gabe observed.